# how to authenticate myself asynchronously on the Google Drive API using AngularJS and HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

Could someone determine how to authenticate myself asynchronously on the Google Drive API using AngularJS and HTML?
 I am getting stuck on the call to gapi.auth.authorize because the callback function never gets called:
 Here is the AngularJS--HTML5 code excerpt  which does not work currently,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.service('googleService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($http, $rootScope, $q) {

                this.login = function () {
                    gapi.auth.authorize(
                      { client_id:  '1009536034660-armd84ckoemm3jan35ceupjhdsmo0fa1.apps.googleusercontent.com', scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' , immediate: true },
                      this.handleAuthResult);



                    return deferred.promise;
                }


                this.handleClientLoad = function {
                    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
                    gapi.auth.init(function () { });
                    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
                };


                this.checkAuth = function () {
                    gapi.auth.authorize({
                        client_id: clientId,
                        scope: scopes,
                        immediate: true,
                        hd: domain
                    }, this.handleAuthResult);
                };


                this.handleAuthResult = function (authResult) {
                    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                        var data = {};
                        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                            var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
                            request.execute(function (resp) {
                                data.email = resp.email;
                                deferred.resolve(data);
                            });
                        });

                    } else {
                        deferred.reject('error');
                    }
                };


                this.handleAuthClick = function (event) {
                    gapi.auth.authorize({
                        client_id: clientId,
                        scope: scopes,
                        immediate: false,
                        hd: domain
                    }, this.handleAuthResult);
                    return false;
                };


 }]);
 app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'googleService', function ($scope, googleService) { 


     $scope.login = function () { 
         $scope.login = function () {
             googleService.login().then(function (greeting) {
                 console.log('Success: ' + greeting);
             }, function (reason) {
                 console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
             }, function (update) {
                 console.log('Got notification: ' + update);
             });

         };

     }; 

 }]); 

    } else {

 deferred.reject('error');

 }

};
```

});

Why is the gapi.auth.authorize failing to call the callback?
First I checked this hypothesis stackoverflow.com/questions/20036893/… and it was incorrect. Next I checked this hypothesis : stackoverflow.com/questions/31659414/… and it was also wrong.

I even tried using Brendan's SetTimeout workaround in this URL, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/GuFxPzqQ9-0 and it did not function properly.

In addition, I requested and obtained a new OAuth2 client id with the correct javascript origin. Evidently , the onload callback is only called after successful loading of the script. Or, is there a timeout possibility for the callback to be invoked?

Here is Windows 7 ASP.NET program written entirely in Javascript and HTML which works properly :

```
<html>

<head>

  <title>Google+ Sign-in button demo: rendering with JavaScript</title>

  <style type="text/css">

  html, body { margin: 0; padding:0;}

  #signin-button {

   padding: 5px;

  }

  #oauth2-results pre { margin: 0; padding:0; width: 600px;}

  .hide { display: none;}

  .show { display: block;}

  </style>



  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      var loginFinished = function (authResult) {

          if (authResult) {

              console.log(authResult);

          }



          gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {

              gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get()

                .execute(function (resp) {

                    // Shows user email

                    console.log(resp.email);

                });

          });



      };



      var options = {

          'callback': loginFinished,

          'approvalprompt': 'force',

          'clientid': '375218714272ao7690jhv6sk7jphi0jf3l5t500sajvt.apps.googleusercontent.com',

          'scopes': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],

          'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity',

          'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'

      };



      var renderBtn = function () {

          gapi.signin.render('renderMe', options);

      }

  </script>



</head>

<body onload ="renderBtn()">

   <div id="renderMe"></div>  

</body>

</html>
```

Could I ask why the Windows 7 ASP.NET Javascript code works okay but not the AngularJS code version?

Answer (score 0):

You have to point $window.location.href at a file in the Windows filesytem which conforms to JavaScript origin naming convention.